# How many years do hero students study at U.A. to become professional heroes?

Tags: my-hero-academia

So far from the anime I remember there is a Class A and a Class B for students, and in episode 24th from season 3, 3 students from a superior year appeared to give a talk to the students from Class A. How many years do hero students study at U.A. until they become professional heroes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 3 years

According to [web-japan.org](https://web-japan.org/kidsweb/explore/schools/) (emphasis mine):

> The basic school system in Japan is composed of elementary school (lasting six years), middle school (three years), **high school (three years),** and university (four years).

Considering that U.A. is a high school, we can conclude that students study for three years before graduating and becoming professional heroes.

However, it may be important to note that in Season 3, Episode 22:

> Class 1-A was able to obtain their provisional hero licences, allowing them to do limited work as pro heroes.

Knowing this, this could change the answer to:

> **Under 1 year.**

I'll leave it to you to decide what the answer is.